# Partially applying a function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, currying

I have the following code :

```
/* Function that takes a list and applies "function" to every element */
struct list *iter(struct list *l, void (*function)(struct list *a));
```

And I have a function `foo(arg1, arg2, struct list *a` that I want to apply to every element of my list.

How can I achieve such a behaviour ? In a programming language that supports closures or currying I would have partially applied `foo` to `arg1` and `arg2`, but it seems to be impossible in C.

Is it possible to have a function return a pointer to a function `bar(struct list *a) = foo(arg1, arg2, a)` ?

Comment: will `arg1` and `arg2` change between each `foo` call?

Comment: What can be changed and what can't be changed?  For instance, if someone said "Use a function `struct list *apply(struct list *head, void (*function)(void *data, struct list *item), void *data);`, would that be violating the constraints you are placed under?

Comment: Well this would force me to write wrapper function for each function that doesn't take a "data" argument and I would rather avoid doing so.

Comment: I tried doing this :
`struct list *iter(struct list *l, void *arg, void (*function)(struct list *a, ...))`

And changing my `iter` function to apply `function(arg, a)` if `arg != NULL` and `function(a)` otherwise.
It doesn't work, let's say I have function foo :
`struct list *foo(struct list *a) {
/* Stuff */
}`
And I want to do `iter(liste, NULL, &foo);`. This doesn't work because the type of `&foo` is different from the type of the function pointer expected by iter.

Is there a way to pass a fixed-argument function pointer to a function that expects a variadic function pointer ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no great way to do this in `C`.

Possible solutions, in order of preference:

1. Iterate the structure in some other way, one that allows you to apply the function yourself.
2. If you can know `arg1` and `arg2` at compile time, just write a function that calls `foo()` with those arguments
3. Make the values of `arg1` and `arg2` global (or static to the file) and set them before you call `iter()`. (Yuck) Usual warnings about anything threaded in this case apply.
4. If you're using GCC and will always use GCC you could use [Nested Functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions).
5. [Do something horrible with variadic functions](http://asg.unige.ch/site/papers/Dami91a.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I achieve such a behaviour ? In a programming language that
>   supports closures or currying I would have partially applied foo to
>   arg1 and arg2, but it seems to be impossible in C.

One way to do it is to use a version of C that provides the features you want. The [Blocks extension to C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29) gives you closures.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your function definition:

```
struct list *iter(struct list *l, void (*function)(struct list *a));
```

I'm assuming that your list consists of a series of `struct list` objects (as opposed to lists which have a separate Head and Node type).

To make the callback more generally usable, you need to supply an extra argument which the caller can tailor to their own needs:

```
struct list *iter( struct list *l, void *arg, void (*function)(void *, struct list *));
```

and inside `iter`, you callback with `function(arg, l);`

Then you invoke `foo` this way:

```
struct foo_args { arg1_t arg1; arg2_t arg2; };   // at file scope

void handler(void *args, struct list *node)    // at file scope
{
    struct foo_args *p_args = args;
    foo(p_args->arg1, p_args->arg2, node);
}

// in a function
struct foo_args args = { arg1, arg2 };
iter(l, &args, handler);
```

Currently you're not using `function`'s return value, typically this can be used for a flag to indicate whether the iteration should break (e.g. because processing this node failed, or it found what it was looking for).